# Pseudo-elements not visible on top of colored background div

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I want to render a photo stack. I used a div with the before- and after-pseudo-elements.
This works fine.
Only caveat is: this div should be rendered on top of some unicolor background. So I place this div inside another div, which has the background color set. Now, the pseudo-elements are not visible anymore. What is going wrong?

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="main">
 <div class="gallery-stackone"></div>
</div>
```

And here the CSS:

```
#main {
background-color: green;
border: 1px solid blue;
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
}

.gallery-stackone {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
    background: red;
    border: 6px solid #fff;
    float: left;
    height: 200px; width: 200px;
    margin: 50px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border: 6px solid #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.gallery-stackone:before {
    content: "";
    height: 200px; width: 200px;
    background: #eff4de;
    border: 6px solid #fff;

    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0px;
    left: -10px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
    transform: rotate(-5deg);
}

.gallery-stackone:after {
    content: "";
    height: 200px; width: 200px;
    background: #768590;
    border: 6px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(4deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(4deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(4deg);
    transform: rotate(4deg);
}
```

Here is the corresponding [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhobkdb2/)

Answer (score 1):

### Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/xhobkdb2/1/)

I've changed the CSS as below

```
#main {
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    position:relative;
    z-index: -2;    
}
```

I've given an `z-index` value to -2 since you have given `z-index:-1` for `.gallery-stackone:after` and for the z-index to work i also added a `position:relative` to the div..

Comment: You're my hero! Thank you!! :-)